# Autocompletion in Firebug expanded console

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, firebug

This one's bugging me since ever. Is it possible to enable autocomplete in Firebug console when it's expanded? In "condensed" mode (which is default) it works like a charm.

I noticed that some plugins ([link](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug-autocompleter/)) offer this functionality, but I'm looking for a more "native" solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551672/code-completion-for-firebug-command-editor ; the answer is: not yet.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the add-on.

Comment: np. I guess we'll have to wait, either for native Firefox devtool (scratchpad) to get mature, or firebug to catch up with it's rival (Chrome devtool console).

Answer (score 0):

Autocompletion in Firebug expanded console is invoked with `Ctrl+space`.

This [long requested feature](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=55#c38) was finally introduced in Firebug version 2.0, March 2014.